# How to combine two serial flows which input depends on other output?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have sophisticated scenario where a set of mutually dependent `coroutine flows` depends on each other and chained:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.cacheAccount(person)
                .flatMapConcat { it->
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "[2] create account call (server)")
                    repository.createAccount(person)
                }
                .flatMapConcat { it ->
                    if (it is Response.Data) {
                        repository.cacheAccount(it.data)
                            .collect { it ->
                                // no op, just execute the command
                                Log.d(App.TAG, "account has been cached")
                            }
                    }
                    flow {
                        emit(it)
                    }
                }
                .catch { e ->
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "[3] get an exception in catch block")
                    Log.e(App.TAG, "Got an exception during network call", e)
                    state.update { state ->
                        val errors = state.errors + getErrorMessage(PersonRepository.Response.Error.Exception(e))
                        state.copy(errors = errors, isLoading = false)
                    }
                }
                .collect { it ->
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "[4] collect the result")
                    updateStateProfile(it)
                }
        }
```

1. cache an account on the local disk
2. create an account on the backend
3. in positive scenario, cache the newly create account in the local disk

Now I have to add more calls to a new API endpoint and the scenario become even more sophisticated. This endpoint is a `ethereum chain`.

4a. In the positive scenario, put in the local disk (cache) initiated transaction `cacheRepository.createChainTx()`

4b. In the negative scenario, just emit further the response from the backend

4a.->5. Register user on the 2nd endpoint `repository.registerUser()`

6. The response from 2nd endpoint put in the cache by updating existing row. Even negative case except of exception should be cached to update status of tx.

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            lateinit var newTx: ITransaction
            cacheRepository.createChainTxAsFlow(RegisterUserTransaction(userWalletAddress = userWalletAddress))
                .map { it ->
                    newTx= it
                    repository.registerUserOnSwapMarket(userWalletAddress)
                }
                .onEach { it -> preProcessResponse(it, newTx) }
                .flowOn(backgroundDispatcher)
                .collect { it -> processResponse(it) }
        }
```

This a scenario which should be integrated into the 1st `Flow chain`.

The issue is I do not see how to do it clear in `Flow chain`. I can rewrite code without chaining, but it also bring variety `if else` statements.

How would you do this scenario in *human readable* way?

Answer (score 0):

I'll ended up with this code for transition period:

```
        viewModelScope.launch(backgroundDispatcher) {
            try {
                var cachedPersonProfile = repository.cacheAccount(person)
                var createAccountResponse = repository.createAccount(person)
                when(createAccountResponse) {
                    is Response.Data -> {
                        repository.cacheAccount(createAccountResponse.data)
                        val cachedTx = cacheRepository.createChainTx(RegisterUserTransaction(userWalletAddress = person.userWalletAddress))
                        val chainTx = walletRepository.registerUserOnSwapMarket(userWalletAddress = person.userWalletAddress)
                        when(chainTx) {
                            is ru.home.swap.core.network.Response.Data -> {
                                if (chainTx.data.isStatusOK()) {
                                    cachedTx.status = TxStatus.TX_MINED
                                } else {
                                    cachedTx.status = TxStatus.TX_REVERTED
                                }
                            }
                            is ru.home.swap.core.network.Response.Error.Message -> {
                                cachedTx.status = TxStatus.TX_EXCEPTION
                            }
                            is ru.home.swap.core.network.Response.Error.Exception -> {
                                cachedTx.status = TxStatus.TX_EXCEPTION
                            }
                        }
                        cacheRepository.createChainTx(cachedTx)
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            state.update { state ->
                                if (cachedTx.status == TxStatus.TX_MINED) {
                                    state.copy(
                                        isLoading = false,
                                        profile = createAccountResponse.data,
                                        status = StateFlagV2.PROFILE
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    val txError = "Failed register the profile on chain with status ${TxStatus.TX_MINED}"
                                    state.copy(
                                        isLoading = false,
                                        errors = state.errors + txError
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else -> { updateStateProfile(createAccountResponse) }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    state.update { state ->
                        val errors = state.errors + getErrorMessage(PersonRepository.Response.Error.Exception(ex))
                        state.copy(errors = errors, isLoading = false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have a better alternative, please share it in the post as an answer.